# Which is Better Performance Wise - if(condition){result} VS if(condition) result;

Tags: php, performance, conditional-statements, curly-brackets

I know the performence difference will be very slight in both scenarios, but I was wondering which is a more practical, performance-improving version to write conditions in PHP.

```
if(condition){
  result;
}
```

VS

```
if(condition)
  result;
```

Comment: Absolutely the same and even in case there would be any difference do you think it's somehow measurable?

Comment: there is no difference for performance...

Comment: Are you talking about the performance of the programmer and/or team of programmers, or just plain speed to run the script?

Comment: If there's any difference at all, the amount of time you spent on writing that question is more than you would gain from using one over the other in your entire lifetime.

Comment: For the close voters as not constructive, why isn't not constructive? I'm probably a duplicate of 10+ question, but is constructive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are exactly the same, it's coding style and has nothing to do with performance. Adapt the style you like better.

Some hint tools suggest to use the first style to avoid mistakes like this:

```
if(condition)
  result;
  foo; // Nothing to do with the condition but you can get confused.
```

While if you were using curly braces, this wouldn't have happen:

```
if(condition){
    result;
}
    foo; // Nothing to do with the condition but now it's clear.
```

I'm not using curly braces by the way for one statement in `if`, as this scenario isn't too difficult to avoid for non noobs.

Answer (score 4):

one line code doesnt require braces; but it is good practice of using braces for one line code too. both are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the difference would be insignificant, if any. I would always you {}, if for no other reason than formatting. I would be surprised if any system these days would have a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to even *think* about this kind of optimization. Whichever way you choose (depends on your personal preferred style), they will perform exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

they are the same from the result and performance point of view but you use

```
if(condition)
  result;
```

only if you have one statement inside , if you have more you use parentheses

Answer (score 0):

If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it.

The following example would display a is bigger than b if $a is bigger than $b:

```
<?php
if ($a > $b)
  echo "a is bigger than b";
?>
```

Often you'd want to have more than one statement to be executed conditionally. Of course, there's no need to wrap each statement with an if clause. Instead, you can group several statements into a statement group. For example, this code would display a is bigger than b if $a is bigger than $b, and would then assign the value of $a into $b:

```
<?php
if ($a > $b) {
  echo "a is bigger than b";
  $b = $a;
}
?>
```

If statements can be nested infinitely within other if statements, which provides you with complete flexibility for conditional execution of the various parts of your program.

for reference use php.net